# Chrome Extension doesn't execute all the way

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The idea is simple. Open a window and then call chrome.tabs.executeScript on that new window.

Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything besides open a new window.

```
function openc(url) {
  window.open(url);
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "removeContent.js"});
  console.log("hi");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  openc("http://www.asdf.com/");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you've got the [host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration) to operate on the page.

If you always want to run the script on the specific page, it suffices to use only content scripts, by [registration via the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration):

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://example.com/*"],
      "js": ["open-asdf.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.asdf.com/*"],
      "js": ["removeContent.js"]
    }
  ],
```

If you want to dynamically execute a content script for the new page, you should use the [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) method to open the new tab, and insert the script in the callback. These methods can only be used in the extension's process, so make sure that the code is running on the background/event/popup/options/.. page.

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'http://www.asdf.com/'
}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "removeContent.js"}, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.create works beautifully. Just a few questions though: what is "tab" in "function(tab)"? And why didn't it work when I tried to use window.open(url)?

Comment: @user2152914 Click on the blue link in my answer, it brings you to the documentation, which explains the meaning of tab. The `tab` provides information about the tab you've just created, whose identifier is passed to `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. `window.open` doesn't provide this identifier, so Chrome doesn't know what you want to insert the content script in that window.